# User ID to Username tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Can someone please tell me how to get one username from one id on tweepy? I have looked everywhere and can't find anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you just have a user_id value you need to call the twitter API with the [get_user(user_id) method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user).
The returned User object will contain the username under screen_name.

```
# steps not shown where you set up api
u = api.get_user(783214)
print u.screen_name
```

If you already have the User object from another API call just look for the screen_name.

Comment: this is what i was trying to get but i figured it out before anyone answered thanks anyway

Comment: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'screen_name'`

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code to get user screen name or user id

**To get user screen name from user id**

```
In [36]: import tweepy
In [37]: consumer_key = Your_consumerkey
In [38]: consumer_secret = Your_consuersecret
In [39]: access_token = Your_access_token
In [40]: access_token_secret = Your_access_token_secret
In [41]: auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
In [42]: auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
In [43]: api = tweepy.API(auth)
In [48]: user = api.get_user(1088398616)                                                           

In [49]: user.screen_name
Out[49]: u'saimadhup'
```

**To get user id from user screen name**

```
In [46]: user = api.get_user(screen_name = 'saimadhup')
In [47]: user.id
Out[47]: 1088398616
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'screen_name'`

Comment: @Liam It's not possible with Essential account. Why and is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 6):

Although OP clearly needs the username for just one id, in case if one wants to get usernames for a list of ids(<100), then:

```
def get_usernames(ids):
    """ can only do lookup in steps of 100;
        so 'ids' should be a list of 100 ids
    """
    user_objs = api.lookup_users(user_ids=ids)
    for user in user_objs:
        print(user.screen_name)
```

For larger set of ids, you can just put this in a `for` loop and call accordingly while obeying the twitter API limit.